# How can i get pyodbc installed in Mac OS X 8.5 (Maountain lion OS)

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, pyodbc

Despite several attempts , I have not been able to build the pyodbc module downloaded from Google codes page.

It fails with the below error message

```html
WARNING: git describe failed with: 32512 
WARNING: Unable to determine version.  Using 3.0.0.0
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/Users/Minat_Verma/Desktop/ProjectFolder
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/Users/Minat_Verma/Desktop/ProjectFolder/MIP
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/Users/Minat_Verma/Desktop/ProjectFolder/MIP/opt
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/Users/Minat_Verma/Desktop/ProjectFolder/MIP/opt/Verica drivers
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/Users/Minat_Verma/Desktop/ProjectFolder/MIP/opt/Verica drivers/pyodbc-master
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/Users/Minat_Verma/Desktop/ProjectFolder/MIP/opt/Verica drivers/pyodbc-master/src
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.0-unsupported -DPYODBC_UNICODE_WIDTH=2 -UMAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c /Users/Minat_Verma/Desktop/ProjectFolder/MIP/opt/Verica drivers/pyodbc-master/src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/Users/Minat_Verma/Desktop/ProjectFolder/MIP/opt/Verica drivers/pyodbc-master/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings -Wno-deprecated-declarations
unable to execute clang: No such file or directory
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Here is the xcode version I am using

BHUKRK263339D:pyodbc-master Minat_Verma$ xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2311.

Am I missing any thing. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't installed the Xcode command line tools.

You can probably do it with the following command:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

else you might have to install them from within Xcode itself.

Comment: Now I have got it installed. Here is the pastebucket of new Set of warnings . (http://goo.gl/SO4o1R) . However since there were no errors I went ahead and tried install assuming successful build. That resulted in error again .here is the install error : (http://goo.gl/HI8tzI)

Comment: @minatverma I think I answered your question and this is not an ongoing support call.  If you have additional issues then start an new question.